# Section Overlapping Transition Animation

Tags: javascript, html

I Have Section Overlapping   Like This.

```js
function forPageOne() {
  document.getElementById('home').style.zIndex = 200;
  document.getElementById('about').style.zIndex = -200;
}

function forPageTwo() {
  document.getElementById('home').style.zIndex = -200;
  document.getElementById('about').style.zIndex = 200;
}
```

```html
<section
  style="
    position: absolute;
    width: 60vh;
    height: 60vh;
    background-color: #144ddc;
    left: 300px;
  "
  class="page1 home"
  id="home"
></section>

<section
  style="
    position: absolute;
    width: 60vh;
    height: 60vh;
    background-color: #dcc114;
    left: 300px;
  "
  class="page2 about"
  id="about"
></section>

<button onclick="forPageOne()">For Page One</button>
<button onclick="forPageTwo()">For Page Two</button>
```

If I Click One Button The Section Is Just Overlapping and I Do Not Need This Just Happen.I need to add the Animation part, one section into another section
And I have no idea how to do this.
If You Can Help with this my problem, I am so thankful About That.
Thank You..!

Example - https://animista.net/play/basic/flip-scale/flip-scale-up-ver
I need to add animation like this when my section is overlapping

Comment: Can you tell me what was `jquery` in this question, plz don't include unnecessary tags 

Comment: Plz, add a brief of what you want to do. Read This: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I am really sorry. I thought this tag can help me with m problem.

Comment: Can you tell what is `Animation part`?

Comment: I Update My Post Again. Please see if you can understand.Sorry for my bad english

Comment: There is no `Animation` in there? What are you talking about.

Comment: No ..There is no Animation Part..I Need to add some animation part of my funtion

Comment: What is this: ***I need to add the Animation part, one section into another section***

Comment: If You see my code snippet when I click the button my section is just overlapping..what I am saying I need to add some animation like this-https://animista.net/play/basic/flip-scale/flip-scale-up-ver

Comment: Now I have understood... Check the answer, I have added it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a class with the animations on click.

```js
const page1 = document.getElementById('home');
const page2 = document.getElementById('about');

function forPageOne() {
  page1.style.zIndex = 200;
  page2.style.zIndex = -200;

  page1.classList.add("animated");
  page2.classList.remove("animated");
}

function forPageTwo() {
  page1.style.zIndex = -200;
  page2.style.zIndex = 200;

  page1.classList.remove("animated");
  page2.classList.add("animated");
}
```

```css
@-webkit-keyframes flip-scale-up-ver {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1) rotateY(0);
    transform: scale(1) rotateY(0);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(2.5) rotateY(90deg);
    transform: scale(2.5) rotateY(90deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1) rotateY(180deg);
    transform: scale(1) rotateY(180deg);
  }
}

@keyframes flip-scale-up-ver {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1) rotateY(0);
    transform: scale(1) rotateY(0);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(2.5) rotateY(90deg);
    transform: scale(2.5) rotateY(90deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1) rotateY(180deg);
    transform: scale(1) rotateY(180deg);
  }
}

.animated {
  -webkit-animation: flip-scale-up-ver 0.5s linear both;
  animation: flip-scale-up-ver 0.5s linear both;
}
```

```html
<section style="
    position: absolute;
    width: 60vh;
    height: 60vh;
    background-color: #144ddc;
    left: 300px;
  " class="page1 home" id="home"></section>

<section style="
    position: absolute;
    width: 60vh;
    height: 60vh;
    background-color: #dcc114;
    left: 300px;
  " class="page2 about" id="about"></section>

<button onclick="forPageOne()">For Page One</button>
<button onclick="forPageTwo()">For Page Two</button>
```